# Kotlin set variable and call method in main class from companion object

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-companion

I'm new to Kotlin, and I don't understand if/how I can call a function or set a variable from the companion object:

```
class MyClass {
    public var myVar: Boolean
    public fun myFunc(): Int { ... }

    companion object {
        private fun doStuff(){
            myVar = true
            myFunc(1)
        }        
    }   
}
```

I get unresolvedReference on `myVar = true` and `myFunc(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Companion object is an object that is not related to any particular *instance* of `MyClass`, therefore it cannot access the *instance* property `myVar` and *instance* function `myFunc` without specifying the instance. It just does not know which instance it should access.

If you really want to do that from a function in the companion object, you should pass it an instance of `MyClass` as well:

```
companion object {
    private fun doStuff(instance: MyClass){
        instance.myVar = true
        instance.myFunc(1)
    }        
}
```